# Finite differences for incompressible viscous fluid equations

Tags: pde, finite-difference, navier-stokes

I am working with the equations for incompressible viscous fluid:

$$
\partial_t \vec{\omega} + (\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{\omega} = \nu\nabla^2\vec{\omega}
$$
$$
\nabla^2 \vec{\psi} = -\vec{\omega}
$$
$$
\vec{u}=\nabla \times \vec{\psi}
$$

with an usual notation:

- $\omega$ ... vorticity
- $u$ ... velocity
- $\nu$ ... kinematic viscosity
- $\psi$ ... stream function

I need to discretize the system (by means of finite differences). Since this is very common tasks, the schemes must be somewhere available, but I was not lucky in googling this time. Could you please share a solution?

Comment: How come? If I type "vorticity equation finite difference" into google, I get 233,000 results. See here: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=vorticity%20equation%20finite%20difference

Comment: One standard method is [Chorin's method](http://math.berkeley.edu/~chorin/chorin67.pdf), also described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_method_(fluid_dynamics)).  It doesn't use the vorticity form, though.